# Php echo html code and dots

Tags: php

I want to echo html code with dots:

```
echo '<li>…</li>' . "\n";
```

But I get

```
<li>���</li>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This is not real dots. Replace'em with `...`

Comment: What you want is called a "horizontal ellipsis". It is best to use the entity code: `&#8230;`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like an encoding problem. You should consider to declare your html in utf8 :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

and make sure your file is utf8 encoded.

Answer (score 2):

Because that's unicode:

Add

```
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> for HTML 4.01 & below
<meta charset="UTF-8"> for HTML5
```

Or execute

`header("content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");`

Or of course just do

```
echo '<li>...</li>' . "\n";
```

With normal full stops.

Did my answer solve your issue? Please make sure to mark it as accepted to help other people with the same problem.